# Multiple SELECT statements in MySQL Query

Tags: mysql

If I have the schemas:

> Type(a,b,c,d)
>
> Name(e, b, g)

I am trying to find all the resulting Name's 'E' where the 'D' of the Type is greater than a number that we access using the shared 'B'.

I am trying to understand how to have multiple SELECT statements such as:

```
SELECT e FROM Name WHERE b = (SELECT b FROM Type WHERE d > 1);
```

Can someone explain the syntax error and how to do nested SELECT statements or do I have to join the two tables.

Thanks

Comment: `=` compares single values. your `(select b)` can return **MULTIPLE** values, which means you have to `where b IN (....)` instead.

Answer (score 2):

This can be accomplished using a simple `INNER JOIN` operation:

```
SELECT DISTINCT n.e 
FROM Name AS n
INNER JOIN Type AS t ON n.b = t.b
WHERE t.d > 1
```

You can also use `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT n.e 
FROM Name AS n
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM Type AS t
              WHERE n.b = t.b AND t.d > 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use `IN` instead of `=`

```
SELECT e FROM Name WHERE b IN (SELECT b FROM Type WHERE d > 1);
```

`=` to compare one value to another value.
`IN` to see if a value exist whiten a list of multiple values.

Comment: It would be much better to use a join.

Comment: @IkeWalkern does better to use `JOIN` make the query wrong?

Comment: Why is a JOIN better if i may ask?

Comment: if you did run multiple `SELECT` statement {`subqueries`}, the engine behind the scene will have to run all the subqueries first to pull the data then run the main `SELECT` statement to get the data based on the results of  the `subqueries`. In the other had when using the `JOIN` the engine will only pull the appropriate row based the relation between the tables and its likely to run faster.